# Large (and frequent) exports from Elasticsearch or Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, architecture, elasticsearch, scalability

A part of the application, I am working on, allows a user to build a query (visually) to export data from the system. Currently, I am building a Elasticsearch query based on the user input and writing a web service that will collect all the results of that query (after applying some basic filters).

After doing some basic benchmarking on the production Elasticsearch cluster, I am starting to doubt if Elasticsearch is the right tool for this. It takes about 22 minutes to export 1 million contacts (from index size of 11 million). There are 3 nodes in the cluster - each with 4 cores, 16 GB ram (heap size 8GB), and EBS storage (I know this is not the most efficient storage for ES).

1. Is Elasticsearch really not well suited for these kind of large volume (and frequent) exports? In my setup Elasticsearch follows Mongo (using transporter plugin), so its possible to get data out from Mongo as well. Would Mongo be a better option? I am bit skeptical to use Mongo considering its not-so-good memory management and also potentially polluting the working set when running export(s).
2. Currently I am pulling data from Elasticsearch over HTTP REST using scroll (and scan api). Its possible that I might get more throughput using Elasticsearch's Java node client or using a plugin like (https://github.com/jprante/elasticsearch-knapsack). Although with knapsack plugin I lose the ability of recording time (and other book-keeping) for each export.

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with the `scroll` and `size` parameters. It depends on the size of your documents, but you could try something like `30s` for scroll and `1000` for `size`.

You retrieve docs at a rate of ~760 docs/s which is not great but as you say, EBS is not fast. Did you try to calculate what the current throughput is and compare it to EBS bandwidth?

A Java client could be a bit faster but I would guess the overhead is somewhere else in this case.